# Mysql/Mariadb command concern

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, mariadb

I'm running Ubuntu 18.0.4. I'm trying to sort my mariadb install.

My understanding is mariadb still includes the "mysql" command line program.

I have installed both mariadb-client mariadb-server, however the mysql commmand line progam does not appear to be available.

Any help would be appreciated.